# Centering text flanked by 2 images using tex4ht

Tags: tex4ht

I am trying to create an HTML page using tex4ht using the following code:

```
\rput[r](-2pt,6pt){\psvectorian[color=black,width=2cm]{41}}
\hfill{}
{\Large \url{Title Text}}
\hfill{}
\rput[l](0,6pt){\psvectorian[color=black,width=2cm]{42}}
\section{New Section}
This is a section. This is a section.
```

What I get is this:

[image: centering]

Is there a better way to center the text and push the images to left/right?

**Edit #1:**

I also want to mention that this problem is only for tex4ht/HTML. For latex + dvipdf, I get:

[image: latex + dvipdf]

**Edit #2:**

I just wanted to post the output from the wonderful answer provided by michal.h21. tex4ht is no doubt powerful, but I find the documentation very hard to understand. Hope this is of help to others:

[image: solution]

Comment: Not related: `\hfill` doesn't take an argument, the `{}` are not needed.

Comment: Thanks - I took them out. Doesn't change the output, as you might expect.

Comment: @Jay - the issue is with HTML generation, as I mention in the edit above.

Comment: @M-V - Seems that I've misread your question. I've removed my comment and I hope you get an answer soon.

Comment: I've never used `tex4ht` (successfully), but my guess would be that `\hfill` is just not parsed for the HTML output (as your output may suggest). Have you tried `\hfill` commands on “normal” (= just text) lines? Do those work?

Comment: You are right, `\hfill` doesn't seem to work for (just) text either in tex4ht.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tex4ht` doesn't know, how to translate your `\hfill` commands to `css`, you must create `css` definitions yourself.

First of all I would create command for title and separate it to package. For example `decosection.sty`:

```
\ProvidesPackage{decosection}
\RequirePackage{psvectorian}
\newcommand\decosection[1]{%
        \dc@leftorn
        \hfill
        {\Large #1}
        \hfill
        \dc@rightorn
}

\newcommand\dc@rightorn{%
        \rput[r](-2pt,6pt){\psvectorian[color=black,width=2cm]{41}}
}

\newcommand\dc@leftorn{%
        \rput[l](0,6pt){\psvectorian[color=black,width=2cm]{42}}
}
```

Now you can use in the document something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{decosection}
\begin{document}
        \decosection{Title Text}

        ble bla ble ble bla ble ble bla ble ble bla ble
        ble bla ble ble bla ble ble bla ble ble bla ble 
        ble bla ble ble bla ble ble bla ble ble bla ble
        ble bla ble ble bla ble ble bla ble ble bla ble
        ble bla ble ble bla ble ble bla ble ble bla ble
\end{document}
```

Because command `\decosection` is in separate package, you can now provide file  named like this package only with extension `.4ht`, `decosection.4ht` in this case.

```
\NewConfigure{decosection}{4}

\renewcommand\decosection[1]{%
\a:decosection%
\dc@leftorn%
\b:decosection%
#1%
\c:decosection%
\dc@rightorn%
\d:decosection%
}
\Configure{decosection}{%
\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP%
\HCode{<div class="decosection"><div class="left-ornament">\Hnewline}
}{\HCode{</div>\Hnewline<div class="decosection-title">}}%
{\HCode{</div>\Hnewline<div class="right-ornament">}}%
{\HCode{</div></div>\Hnewline}}%
\Css{%
        .decosection{
                width:100\%;
                clear:both;
                overflow:auto;
        }
        .left-ornament, .decosection-title, .right-ornament{
                float:left;
        }
        .left-ornament{
                width:25\%;
        }
        .decosection-title{
                text-align:center;
                width:50\%;
                font-size:200\%;
        }
        .right-ornament{
                width:25\%;
                text-align:right;
        }
}
```

this file is called automatically when `tex4ht` loads `decosection.sty`. We need to create so called `hooks` which are configurable places, where we later put `html` tags. With command `\NewConfigure` we created four hooks, because we need to put them at the beginning, at the end and between the elements. These hooks are named `\a:docusection` ... `\d:docusection`

then we need to redefine the command and put the hooks to their places. As you see there is no need for commands that change appereance, like `\hfill` or `\large`. Visual output is job for tags from hooks and `css`.

with `\Configure`, we put in some tags, in this case only `<div>` with various `class` attributes, which are used by `css` for styling the appearance.

finally, `\Css` command is used for putting `css` definitions.

Comment: Wow, that's phenomenal. Now I have to read this about 100 times so something gets into my head. Thanks!

Comment: @M-V yeah sorry for my english, it took for me 10x more time to write the description, than to write the actual code :) you can search for `tex4ht` on this site, there are some good questions and answers about configuring `tex4ht`, maybe easier to understand :)

Comment: Your English is fine. My knowledge of TeX on the other hand... Thanks again. :-)